# Error while creating autodesk forge viewer extension in angular

Tags: angular, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I wrote an extension for the forge viewer (using angular) but its giving a runtime error saying Autodesk is not defined

```
export class MyExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {

  public static extensionName: string = 'MyExtension';
 
  public load() {
    console.log('MyExtension loaded!');
    return true;
  }
 
  public unload() {
    console.log('MyExtension unloaded.');
    return true;
  }
}
```

I did an npm install @types/forge-viewer and am able to use Autodesk inside a class without any error, just not able to extend it. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Edit: This question seems to be similar to my problem, but I don't understand how the op created the Extension class or how its actually extending the Autodesk.Viewing.Extension since they didn't provide code for that. [Using Forge Javascript-based Extension in Angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60743272/using-forge-javascript-based-extension-in-angular-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@types/forge-viewer` module only includes type definitions, not the actual Forge Viewer code. The viewer code is obtained from https://developer.api.autodesk.com, for example:

- https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js, or
- https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js

This library must be loaded *before* you start defining your viewer extension classes.